# Sending Keys to Text Area with Selenium Python3

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to send keys to a textarea on quizlet. My code is raising an exception, I am not sure what-for some reason my except is not printing it. Just says "Message:" and nothing else. My issue is with code immediately after the comment.

```
    try:
    driver=webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get('https://quizlet.com/')
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,r'//*[@id="SiteHeaderReactTarget"]/header/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/span[2]/div/div[2]/div/button[1]'))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, r'username'))).send_keys(entry1.get())
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, r'password'))).send_keys(entry2.get())
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,r'/html/body/div[7]/div/div[2]/form/button'))).click()
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,r'//*[@id="SiteHeaderReactTarget"]/header/div/div[1]/div[2]/span[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/a'))).click()
    except:
        WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,r'//*[@id="SiteHeaderReactTarget"]/header/div/div[1]/div[2]/span[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/a'))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,r'/html/body/div[7]/div/div[1]/div'))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,r'//*[@id="SetPageTarget"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/label/div/div/div[2]/textarea'))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,r'//*[@id="SetPageTarget"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/label/div/div/div[2]/textarea'))).send_keys(title.get())
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,r'//*[@id="SetPageTarget"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/label/div/div/div[2]/textarea'))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,r'//*[@id="SetPageTarget"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/label/div/div/div[2]/textarea'))).send_keys(description.get())
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,r'//*[@id="SetPageTarget"]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/button'))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,r'ui-control-00d71c59-9975-4578-ae9f-9908b114e36a'))).click()
    #deleted everything after this, having some issue, will have to figure it out tomorrow. Slowly work through the quizlet website again
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, r'//*[@id="SetPageTarget"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/form/textarea'))).send_keys('list')
    time.sleep(10)
    driver.quit()
except Exception as e:
    driver.quit()
    print(e)
```

Here is the HTML of the class that I am trying to interact with:

If necessary, one can log onto quizlet, click create new study set, and then click import and they will see the desired textarea.

Comment: Wow, for some reason I cannot add the html to the post.

Comment: Change your locator to XPATH.
You are using By.CLASS_NAME locator and  giving XPATH.

Comment: oh jeez, can't believe I didn't notice that

Comment: Wow. The problem was not with that line of code. Earlier I was trying to click on an element that I had already clicked on.